# WPF data picker Selected date changed event handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, datepicker

I am trying to add an event handler to a date picker control programmatically during the window load process, but it is  giving me an error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventHandler' to
>   'System.EventHandler'

The code:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadCombo();
            dpFrom.SelectedDateChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(this.dp_SelectedDateChanged);

        }

private void dp_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   // reset label;                    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try the short form (syntactical sugar):

```
dpFrom.SelectedDateChanged += this.dp_SelectedDateChanged;
```

(this is usually automatically generated when coding in Visual Studio)